# vertical align with flexbox in IE11 and IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

How to make a cross browser solution where an element is vertical aligned?

http://jsfiddle.net/e2yuqtdt/3/

This works in both Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE11

```
<div class="page_login">
    <div>vertical-align:center; text-align:center</div>
</div>

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

.page_login {
    display:flex;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#303030;
}

.page_login > div {
    margin:auto;
    background:#fff;
    min-height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
```

## update

When the centered element is higher than the viewport height the background is only 100% and not 100% scroll height

http://jsfiddle.net/e2yuqtdt/8/

```
html, body {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.page_login {
    display:flex;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#303030;
}

.page_login > div {
    margin:auto;
    background:#fff;
    height:800px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to make a cross browser solution where an element is vertical
>   aligned?

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ry8vqkL/

The technique applied there is using the "display: table". Here is an article for an in-depth view of the approach http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Supported browsers can be seen here: http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="page-login">
        <div class="panel">Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    display: table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#303030;
}

#page-login {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.panel {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: seems we had same idea

Comment: Yea. I prefer this way of centering rather than the still "new" flexbox.

Comment: It's 2019 and I was trying to use flexbox to vertically center something...still not working properly in IE11. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a height to the div. As you have only specified a minimum height, IE automatically expands it to the max possible. So add a height, like this:

```
.page_login > div {
     margin:auto;
     background:#fff;
     min-height:100px;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e2yuqtdt/6/

As this is a flex box, and therefore meant to flex, a good idea could be to make the height a percentage. So the div height would be - for example - 50% of the page height, unless the page was less than 200px high - then it would be 100px high.

**Update**: <del>Unfortunatly it is not possible to make the div fill the whole page with only CSS. However it seems it is possible with Javascript, see here [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)</del>

Actually - have achived it using <del>tables</del> divs

http://jsfiddle.net/e2yuqtdt/14/

```
<div>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">vertical-align:center; text-align:center</div>
    </div>
</div>


#div1 {
    display:flex;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#303030;
}

#div2 {
    margin:auto;
    background:#fff;
    height:800px;
    width:200px;
}
```

I know this update is coming after the one by elad.chen - but had already done this and posted it in the comment below - just hadn't got round to updating the question.

Comment: A new problem.. When the centered element is higher than viewport the background is only 100% and not 100% scroll height.. have updated question with new fiddle

Comment: yes.. but would like to do it the "right" way without tables.. if you use tables you could make the layout with tables alone - without flexbox :)

Comment: @clarkk What about this http://jsfiddle.net/e2yuqtdt/13/ - with divs instead of tables

Comment: the fiddle returns 404

Comment: @clarkk sorry hadnt clicked save :D

Comment: Thats better! :D but you don't even need styling on the outer div.. look here http://jsfiddle.net/e2yuqtdt/14/

Comment: Great :D - updating my answer :|

Comment: hmm.. its still nok working properly.. if the centered element is smaller than viewport height..